# JSTL use #{...} value in sql query

Tags: mysql, jsp, jsf, jstl

I am new to jsp and in my jstl script I would like to execute a sql query that will retrieve values based on the value provided from the data

```
    SELECT Checked from oss_hb_check WHERE MLS='#{offer.propertyVO.propertyMLS}';
```

I have also tried with

```
    SELECT Checked from oss_hb_check WHERE MLS='<h:outputText value="#{offer.propertyVO.propertyMLS}"/>';
```

Where as the # value is returned in the html properly in this line,

```
    <h:commandLink styleClass="#{offer.propertyBuyerAgentVO.style}" value="#{offer.propertyVO.propertyMLS}" action="#{ossBean.offerDetails}"></h:commandLink>
```

Please like to know whether the sql query is possible or not.

Comment: Can't you just get it from bean property which EL connects to? Also beware of sql injection.

Comment: @Geinmachi  Actually the bean property are compiled class files and I dont have the source code. So like to know is there a way to do it

Comment: JSTL? Where's JSTL in the question? Are you talking about `<sql:xxx>` tags which was discouraged since more than a decade? Nonetheless, executing SQL usually happens in a business service / DAO class, not in a JSP/JSF page.

Comment: @BalusC Yes the <sql:query> tags are used by me in the jsf file. I am completely new to this and ok I will try using the DAO class. For the existing DAO classes I dont have the source code so can I use class decompiler for it (JD-GUI is the decompiler I used). Will it work if I recompile the decompiled  files.